# probleme with error A2206: missing operator in expression

Tags: assembly, masm

Hi guys I have this code here in assembly it should create a message box but when I try to compile it with Masm

I get this error: C:..\test.asm(26) : error A2206: missing operator in expression

```
.386 .model flat, stdcall

option casemap:none

includelib C:\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib    
includelib C:\masm32\lib\user32.lib    
include C:\masm32\include\kernel32.inc    
include C:\masm32\include\user32.inc    
include C:\masm32\include\windows.inc

.data MsgText db "Hello World!",0

MsgTitle db "My First MessageBox",0

.code

Main:

xor ebx,ebx    
xor ecx,ecx    
push offset MsgTitle ;title    
mov ebx,esp    
push offset MsgText    ;text    
mov ecx,esp    
xor eax,eax       
push eax    
push ebx    
push ecx  
push eax    
xor esi,esi 

**mov esi, 0x7655ea71 (absolute addresses of windows function MessageBoxA within USER32.DLL)**

jmp esi

end Main
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Should be

```
    mov esi, 7655ea71h
```

Note the `h` instead of `0x`

Comment: You can also remove that `DWORD PTR` bit, just yse the proper notation of a hex value. I tested it on masm32 and it works here.

Comment: BTW, if the first character of the number is A-F you must have a leading 0. If it is a number, like in your example, you can have it as well, but don't need to.